# Bigquery combining repeated fields from 2 different tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 tables:

To keep problem definition simple, here is the schema for 1st:

```
student_id int
phones repeated 
- phones.number string
- phones.type string
```

2nd table:

```
student_id int
courses repeated 
- courses.id int
- courses.name string
```

Both tables have same number of rows and same student ids. All I need is to combine both repeated records into one master student table: (keeping 2 distinct repeating fields)
something like:

```
student_id int
phones repeated 
- phones.number string
- phones.type string
courses repeated 
- courses.id int 
- courses.name string
```

How can i do this in bigquery ? (I tried a bunch of approaches, but all ended up creating repeating rows for repeated fields. It would be good to get a fresh perspective from bigquery masters on stackoverflow). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to `JOIN` the two data sets and select the relevant columns from each. It's easier to set up an example using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options") but a similar idea applies to legacy SQL.

```
WITH Students AS (
  SELECT
    1 AS student_id,
    ARRAY<STRUCT<number STRING, type STRING>>[
      STRUCT("(555) 555-5555", "cell")] AS phones
  UNION ALL SELECT
    5 AS student_id,
    ARRAY<STRUCT<number STRING, type STRING>>[
      STRUCT("(555) 555-1234", "home"),
      STRUCT("(555) 555-4321", "cell")] AS phones
),
Courses AS (
  SELECT
    5 AS student_id,
    ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, name STRING>>[
      STRUCT(10, "Data Analysis")] AS courses
  UNION ALL SELECT
    1 AS student_id,
    ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, name STRING>>[
      STRUCT(10, "Data Analysis"),
      STRUCT(101, "Algorithms")] AS courses
)
SELECT
  student_id,
  phones,
  courses
FROM Students
JOIN Courses
USING (student_id);
```

Legacy SQL would use something like:

```
SELECT
  s.student_id AS student_id,
  s.phones.number,
  s.phones.type,
  c.courses.id,
  c.courses.name
FROM Students s
JOIN Courses c
ON s.student_id = c.student_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

for Legacy SQL

```
SELECT 
   s.student_id AS student_id,
   phones.number,
   phones.type,
   courses.id,
   courses.name
FROM Students s
JOIN Courses c
ON s.student_id = c.student_id
```

Note: *you will need to check `Allow Large Results` checkbox and uncheck `Flatten Results` checkbox with save result into table to preserve schema*

Comment: my choice would definitely go with Standard SQL option as in @ElliottBrossard answer

Comment: Oops, I had missed the fact that legacy SQL won't allow selecting non-leaf fields; I updated my example. But yes, +1 to using standard SQL if you can.