# Bigquery multiple unnest in a single select

Tags: google-bigquery

Following up on this - 
[Bigquery combining repeated fields from 2 different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961036/bigquery-combining-repeated-fields-from-2-different-tables)

The above solution from @ElliottBrossard was what I was looking for. Thanks! I need to UNNEST the fields from above to get aggregations by student. Say, there is an additional field for cost (per course) For e.g. assuming the output from the above in a student_courses table, I will need to do something like,

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT phone.number),
  COUNT(DISTINCT courses.Id),
  SUM(courses.Cost)
FROM
  student_courses,
  UNNEST(phone),
  UNNEST(courses)
```

My expected answer from the above is something like, 3, 4, $800 (assuming the 4 courses cost $200 each). The above query ends up acting like a cross join. Is it possible to get aggregate from multiple nests using a single Select?

Answer (score 6):

Here's an idea, although it's a bit verbose:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT number)
   FROM UNNEST(numbers) AS number),
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT course_id)
   FROM UNNEST(course_ids) AS course_id),
  course_sum
FROM (
  SELECT
    ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(
      ARRAY(SELECT number FROM UNNEST(phone))
    ) AS numbers,
    ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(
      ARRAY(SELECT id FROM UNNEST(courses))
    ) AS course_ids,
    SUM((SELECT SUM(cost) FROM UNNEST(courses))) AS course_sum
  FROM YourTable
);
```

References:

- [`ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_concat_agg)
- [`UNNEST`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Elliott, that helps. I should probably add some context. We are trying to build data structures like above to support adhoc reporting using Tableau. Given the recommendations to use nested structures, we are trying to replace our denormalized/flattened model without compromising the simplicity from an end user standpoint. Since we have 100s of measures, the above may not be feasible from an implementation standpoint.

Comment: To clarify, you have hundreds of independently repeating fields over which you want to perform distinct counts? I wrote an answer for the question that you asked...not the one that you did not communicate.

Comment: and hence the clarification from my part :)

Comment: And hence the clarification from my part :). We are using bigquery as our warehousing solution and are trying to push the limit by trying to consolidate. A simple example is client tracking. Client generates revenue, has several touch points on our site, and independently maintains several accounts with us. For a business user wanting to do behavior analysis on clients, they want to track visits, revenue generated and how their accounts impac retention, we are trying to evaluate if a nested structure would work for us.

Comment: Please submit a different question with all relevant requirements in that case, then.