# Statistical functions on columns of arrays in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

If I have data that looks like the follows:

```
+------+------------+-------+
| a    | val        |  val2 |
+------+------------+-------+
| 3.14 | [1, 2, 3]  | [2, 3]|
| 1.59 | [7, 8, 9]  |  ...  |
| -1   | [4, 5, 6]  |  ...  |
+------+------------+-------+
```

and I want to get the array averages of the `val` column, naively I'd want to just try something like

```
SELECT 
  AVG(val)
FROM 
  <Table>
```

But that doesn't work. I get an error like `No matching signature for aggregate function AVG for argument types: ARRAY<INT64>. Supported signatures: AVG(INT64); AVG(UINT64); AVG(DOUBLE); AVG(NUMERIC)`

I know that if I have just one column `val` I can do something like

```
SELECT avg
FROM 
  (
    SELECT AVG(val) as avg
    FROM UNNEST(val) AS val
   )
```

but what if I have multiple columns (`val`, `val2`, etc.) and need multiple statistics? The above method just seems really cumbersome.

To be clear the result I'd want is:

```
 +------+------------+-------------+--------------+
 | a    | avg_val    | std_dev_val |  avg_val2    |
 +------+------------+-------------+--------------+
 | 3.14 |    2       |      1      |    ...       |
 | 1.59 |    8       |     ....    |    ...       |
 | -1   |    5       |     ....    |    ...       |
 +------+------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Is there a simple way to do this? Or do I need to create some sort of temporary function to accomplish this? Or am I stuck doing something like what I see in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45560462/1902480

Comment: And this is one of the many reasons why you don't store data in an array in the DB

Comment: @Charlieface Agreed. That's what I've learned from this experience. Unfortunately it wasn't my choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below example

```
#standardSQL
create temp function array_avg(arr any type) as ((
  select avg(val) from unnest(arr) val
));
create temp function array_std_dev(arr any type) as ((
  select stddev(val) from unnest(arr) val
));
select a, 
  val, array_avg(val) val_avg, array_std_dev(val) val_stddev,
  val2, array_avg(val2) val2_avg, array_std_dev(val2) val2_stddev
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want the average as an array, you can unnest and then reaggregate:

```
select array_agg(avg_val order by n)
from (select n, avg(val) as avg_val
      from t cross join
           unnest(vals) v with offset n
      group by n
     ) a;
```

EDIT:

If you want the values per row, just use a subquery with `unnest()`:

```
select t.*,
       (select avg(el)
        from unnest(t.val) el
       ),
       (select avg(el)
        from unnest(t.val2) el
       )
from t;
```

And so on for whatever aggregation functions you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think simple subqueries should be fine - `AVG()` only works with tables and `UNNEST()` turns arrays into tables - so you can just combine them:

```sql
SELECT 
  (SELECT AVG(val) FROM UNNEST(val1) as val) AS avg_val1,
  (SELECT AVG(val) FROM UNNEST(val2) as val) AS avg_val2,
  (SELECT AVG(val) FROM UNNEST(val3) as val) AS avg_val3 
FROM 
  <table>
```

`val1`, `val2` and `val3` are looked up as columns in `<table>` while `val` within the subqueries will be looked up in the table coming from the respective `UNNEST()`.